# Encrypt (cryptojs) - Decrypt (.NET)

Tags: javascript, .net, cryptojs

Passwords are going to be encrypted in .NET using AES and stored in a database. In another application, using javascript (on top of a Rhino engine) and the cryptojs library, I'll need to decrypt the password and then use it.

The solution doesn't need to be complex, all I'm seeking is a simple implementation of how I can get these two guys to work together.

Followed this guide: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AES-Encryption-Decryption-Cryptography-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Successfully encrypted a simple string ("SFTPPass") with a key of ("Key") in .NET, but once I get to decrypting in javascript not sure how to do it.

This is what I have in javascript:

```
var encryptedPass = 'StrmZO1Vjd8noHYzXs8hiQQBQDJZA5Bpg3t4BcmrViU=';

var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('1Ph1oX+N+q/kzpdyaIKBpA==');
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('k/W+Xeenh3kSLneZ/DYXVpvshGbsFVdyfOFdFTJb1yE=');

var SFTPPass = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedPass, 'Key', key, {iv: iv});
```

However when I write my output to a file it's empty.

Any suggestions or alternative solutions are greatly welcomed!

EDIT:
With the recommendation by alancnet, I'm now getting output but the string doesn't match the original which is "1234". So I followed the guide in the link above down to the wire using the same Key Phrase and input string. Captured the hex of both the key & iv using BitConverter.toString in .NET.

```
key = "752DA9F0D612540EEF1DE07A144781261A3D604DE339174ADAC5D5D6A695ABFF"
iv = "9714413594225F1D14FA02101C0D584D"
```

What my javascript looks like now:

```
var encryptedPass = 'Ao5ZnFYo344iWqv/Jr9euw==';

var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('9714413594225F1D14FA02101C0D584D');
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('752DA9F0D612540EEF1DE07A144781261A3D604DE339174ADAC5D5D6A695ABFF');

var decryptedString = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedPass, key, {iv: iv});
```

Comment: Please show how you're outputing to a file.

Comment: That's going to be difficult to explain. So I'm using a separate application (that's uses Rhino as the scripting engine) built with Java. In this application they make use of an option called "File Writer" which I give it a string (SFTPPass) and it automatically takes care of the details for writing to a file. The program is called Mirth Connect.

EDIT:
Now that I think about it, did you mean how I'm outputting from .NET?

Comment: I suspect it is doing SOMETHING, but the failure is in writing the file. Is there any way you can inject your own code here to output somewhere else? Or can you debug it and inspect the variables at a breakpoint?

Comment: Can you clarify if we're talking about the output from .NET or from JavaScript?

Comment: in JavaScript. Can you directly inspect the value of SFTPPass?

Comment: Unfortunately no, my only option is to output to a file to confirm if things are going as planned. I really doubt that it's my File Writer, I'm leaning towards that the problem is stemming from my process of how the string gets encrypted in .NET and then decrypted using the CryptoJS library, just not exactly sure which one isn't working properly.

Comment: I understand, but it's important we know for SURE that the FileWriter is working, because at this point, it's the elephant in the room. Can you add a header and footer to the file, so that we can see if any output is happening at all?

Comment: For instance `FileWriter.write("[" + SFTPPass + "]");`

Comment: oh sorry I was misunderstanding you. The File Writer does work, I can pass any other normal string ("testString") and it will output that string just fine. But when I try to pass my var SFTPPass which is supposed to represent the decrypted version of the string, that's when nothing get outputted.

Comment: For anyone looking for a complete example see https://github.com/Lavinski/CryptoTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
var SFTPPass = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedPass, 'Key', key, {iv: iv});
```

`'Key'` is an unexpected parameter, and should be removed.

I ported your code to Node:

```
var CryptoJS = new require("cryptojs").Crypto;

var encryptedPass = 'StrmZO1Vjd8noHYzXs8hiQQBQDJZA5Bpg3t4BcmrViU=';

var iv = CryptoJS.util.base64ToBytes('1Ph1oX+N+q/kzpdyaIKBpA==');
var key = CryptoJS.util.base64ToBytes('k/W+Xeenh3kSLneZ/DYXVpvshGbsFVdyfOFdFTJb1yE=');

var SFTPPass = CryptoJS.util.bytesToBase64(
        CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            encryptedPass, 
            key, 
            {
                iv: iv, 
                asBytes: true
            }
        )
    );

console.log(SFTPPass);
```

and it ouput: `UABfRxZLApVrt/t8JtoHMhCxfYUPWDwMLuBmWe50tDw=`

Good luck :)

Comment: yeah that was a dumb mistake on my part. I updated my original post, feel free to try the values I posted to see if you're still getting the expected output. Instead of the base64 string, are you able output what the original string would be, which is "1234"?

Comment: You can `new Buffer(bytes).toString()`, but when I did that, I got jibberish. Which means the values are incorrect, but the code works.

Comment: How about an up-arrow and a green check mark for your old buddy? I'm working on raising rep here :)

Comment: I'll definitely come back and do that when I've got enough rep points, I only have 11 of them. :(

Comment: Yay i finally have enough.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was the format of how I was outputting the decrypted string.

Played around with multiple versions...

```
 FileWrite(decryptedString);
 FileWrite(decryptedString.toString());
```

Ultimately what got it working was:

```
 FileWrite(decryptedString.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Mind you the lower case of "t" and "f", tried doing "UTF8" and it gave me completely different output as well.

Thanks again to alancnet for pointing out the main mistake I was doing in trying to use an invalid parameter, i probably wouldn't have noticed that till later in the day.